# Why am I seeing the error "Your payment session has expired. Please return to the participating website and try again."

Tags: paypal-sandbox

Since this morning Feb 2nd, 2015, I get an error when I go through the payment flow in the PayPal Sandbox environment. Has anybody come across this error? Any idea what changed or could have caused this error? To be clear, there's been no change to the application which integrates with PayPal Sandbox. All tests related to the payment flow were passing till yesterday. Checked the application logs and I don't see any errors there.

Comment: Looks like the folks who maintain PayPal Sandbox fixed it on their end. I don't see this issue anymore. Is there a status page for Sandbox that I can look at to see if there are any known issues with the service going forward?

Comment: unfortunately no. paypal api is very confusing